# sql result as array of arrays

Tags: php, sql, arrays, output

i'm trying to format the output of a sql query as an array of arrays, for using the gannti class graph tool on my sql data. I'm not very experienced(outside industrial plc's), and can't seem to find a solution to this particular problem despite lots of googeling.

The sql query i want to perform looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT label, start, end from oppgaver ";
```

And the original array showed in the gannti class example is written like this:

```
$data = array();

data[] = array(
  'label' => 'alarmkit',
  'start' => '2013-08-01',
  'end'   => '2013-09-10'
);

$data[] = array(
  'label' => 'Stekeovnskontroller',
  'start' => '2013-08-22',
  'end'   => '2013-09-01'
);

$data[] = array(
  'label' => 'Tull og fanteri',
  'start' => '2013-09-02',
  'end'   => '2013-09-10'
);
```

And then you call the gantti to do it's thing:

```
$gantti = new Gantti($data, array(
  'title'      => 'Elektro',
  'cellwidth'  => 15,
  'cellheight' => 35,
  'today'      => true
));
```

All works well, except for my unability to format the sql output to what i assume is an array of arrays so the gantti class can do its magic. I got it to show the first letter of each label in the sql database once, but that piece of mangled code i wrote should probably be forgotten :-)

Does anyone here have a idea about how to do this?

Update:

The last way i tried to get the data, by using msql_fetch_assoc.
Unfortunately i did not keep a record of the different approaches i made.
I've also tried several examples i found on using mysql_fetch_array, and mysql_fetch_row.

```
$query = "SELECT label, start, end from oppgaver ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row[0]);
        }
```

Comment: [Update your question with how you are reading the data you get from your query so we can help you on what you're missing there.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18396878/edit)

Comment: Have you tried array_push($data, $row); to push the whole array, not just a column?

Comment: array_push($data, $row); did the trick, instead of blank screens i get correct output. Thanks a lot for the help and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$row` to push in array in place of `$row[0]`

As given below

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row);
        }
```